# How to return the cell contents based on matching heading and row labels

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel table where the column headings are companies, and the row labels are dates. e.g.

```
             Company A  Company B   Company C
25/03/2018          50      
03/04/2018                               10
13/06/2018                   25 
13/06/2018          10      
06/07/2018                   10
```

All column headings are unique but sometimes row labels will have the same dates.

On another sheet I will have rows stating the date and company name. What formula should I use to get the value that corresponds to the intersection of the company name and date provided?

I can use MATCH to tell me the Company Column I should be looking at, but don't know how to tell it to search the dates next to the entries in those columns. VLOOKUP seems to get tripped up by the fact that sometimes the Row label isn't unique.

Comment: FYI this gets you close - `=INDEX($B$2:$D$6,MATCH(A9,$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(B9,$B$1:$D$1,0))` where `A9` is a date, and `B9` is a company name, i.e. `Company A`...except it returns empty/0 for the Company A 13/06/2018.  Since it's looking for an entry, it takes the first match it finds, which in your example is an empty cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sometimes the Row label isn't unique` instead of VLOOKUP try SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,DATE(2018,6,13),INDEX($B:$D,0,MATCH("Company A",$B$1:$D$1,0)))
```

Adjust cell references to suit your actual data.  Note that you can replace the `DATE(2018,6,13)` and `"Company A"` with cell references.